# merge rows of one file based on key columns

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a text file which has ~ delimiter values. first 4 columns are the key columns and based on that 5th column value needs to be extracted. The file looks like this:

```
S1~D1~1~1~abc
S1~D1~1~1~bef
S2~D1~1~2~xyz
S2~D1~1~2~mnp
```

the output should look like

```
S1~D1~1~1~abcbef
S2~D1~1~2~xyzmnp
```

the last column has sometimes linebreaks which should be removed as it will merge two rows correctly.

Comment: Will there ever be more than two rows with the same identifier?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
  BEGIN{OFS = FS = "~"} 
  {x = $5; NF--; a[$0] = a[$0] x; next} 
  END{for(i in a) print i, a[i]}
' file
S1~D1~1~1~abcbef
S2~D1~1~2~xyzmnp
```

Comment: this doesn't work, the output file is coming as blank

Comment: @anonymous, works for me. Did you put your real filename where "file" is now?

Comment: works for me (btw the `; next` seems unnecessary) - https://tio.run/##SyzP/v/fydXd06/a3y1YwVYBTCjVKdUqcCkoVFcAOSqm1gp@brq61gqJ0SoGsUARCF1hrZCXWlECVujq51Kdll@kkamQmaeQqKlQUJSZV6KQqQNUmhlb@/9/sGGdi2EdCCYmJXMheEmpaVzBRhCeUV1FZRUSLzevAAA

Comment: TBH I didn't attempt to address the "sometimes" linebreaks in the last column because I wasn't sure what the OP meant - maybe that's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok using Python with Pandas:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# combine_by_keys.py
# Take input file with tilde-delimited keys and combine strings with exact key
# match.
#
# ./combine.py myfile.txt
#
import pandas as pd
import re
import sys

filename = sys.argv[1]

# Read keys and strings into lists.
keys = list()                
strings = list()             
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        key, string = line.strip().rsplit('~', 1)
        keys.append(key)
        strings.append(string)

print(re.sub(
        r'\ +',  # Pandas separates index and values with spaces.
        '~',     # Replace spaces with tilde.
        pd.DataFrame({'keys':keys,'strings':strings})
                .groupby('keys')['strings']
                .apply(lambda x:''.join(x))
                .to_string(header=False)))
```

Use it on a data file like this.

```
$ cat myfile.txt 
S1~D1~1~1~abc
S1~D1~1~1~bef
S2~D1~1~2~xyz
S2~D1~1~2~mnp

$ ./combine_by_keys.py myfile.txt 
S1~D1~1~1~abcbef
S2~D1~1~2~xyzmnp
```